# Loading only single language JSON file in Angular multilaguage

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, ionic-framework

I am working on ionic application. I want to add multi-language support for the same using language .json files. So I googled it and found few examples for loading files using "angular static file loader plugin", but it loads all the language files at once.

My question is, can we load user selected language file only to avoid extra time for loading other language files. Can anybody please let me know how can I achieve it ?? or loading all files at a time is better approach ?? or is there any better implementation I can do ??

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My question is, can we load user selected language file only to avoid extra time for loading other language files.

Yes.

> Can anybody please let me know how can I achieve it ?? or loading all files at a time is better approach ?? or is there any better implementation I can do ??

Use [`angular-translate`](https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate) and [`angular-translate-loader-url`](https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate/wiki/Asynchronous-loading#using-extension-translateurlloader)

in your `app.config()`

```
$translateProvider.useUrlLoader('/translate');
$translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en_US');
```

This will be an equivalent of request `/translate?lang=en_US` to get the specific language (default) when your app initial.

Later when you want to change to another language:

```
// Example in one of your controller
$translate.use('fr_FR');
```

This will trigger a request `/translate?lang=fr_FR` to fetch another translation file

> I have created JSON files of language as "en.json" in my project.. and I want to use that file.. so is it possible by using above code?

For JSON files, as mentioned in your question `angular-translate-loader-static-files` Will do the trick (I am not sure why you have all file loaded in once, because it supposed to be lazy loading)

```
$translateProvider.useStaticFilesLoader({
    prefix: '',
    suffix: '.json'
});
$translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en');
```

This will load `en.json`.

To lazy load another translation file.

```
$translate.uses('fr');
```

This will load `fr.json`

Comment: I have created JSON files of language as "en.json" in my project.. and I want to use that file.. so is it possible by using above code?

Comment: @Mr.Noddy updated answer, according to your comment. Please check again

Comment: ok... @Linh... thanks for the answer... ok its lazy loading... so I hope its good approach.. and I can go with it... right??

Comment: For long run, go with `angular-translate-loader-url` you got an advantage when things are handled by server side. Which mean easier to config cache... autonomus update... etc... so it will run faster. ----- If you do not have (or wanted to) involved with server side `angular-translate-loader-static-files` will be just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Best way to change language Globally is to use pipes and send the language parameter as an argument.
This would automatically change the Language across the components where the language pipe is utilized.
The following example can be used to supple multiple language at a time and can be used to change Language dynamically on a single click

```
// for example: **language.pipe.ts**

import { Pipe, PipeTransform, OnInit, OnChanges } from '@angular/core';
import { LanguageService } from '../services/language.service';

@Pipe({
    name: 'language'
})
export class LanguagePipe implements PipeTransform {

    constructor(
        public lang: LanguageService
    ) { }

    transform(value: string, args?: any): any {
        return this.lang.getLang(value);
    }
}


// **language.service.ts**

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class LanguageService {

    selectedLanguage = 'ch';
    segmentsNames: any = {};
    constantSegmentNames: any = {};
    language = {
        undefined: { 'en': '', 'ch': '' },
        null: { 'en': '', 'ch': '' },
        '': { 'en': '', 'ch': '' },
        'hello': { 'en': 'Hello', 'ch': '你好' },
        'world': { 'en': 'World', 'ch': '世界' }
    };

    constructor(private _http: HttpClient) { }

    getLang(value: string, args?: any): any {
        if (this.language[value]) {
            return this.language[value][this.selectedLanguage];
        }
        return value;
    }

    /**
     * @function that is used to toggle the selected language among 'en' and 'ch'
     */
    changeLanguage() {
        if (this.selectedLanguage === 'en') {
            this.selectedLanguage = 'ch';
        } else {
            this.selectedLanguage = 'en';
        }
    }
}


// **Use Language Pipe in HTML AS**

<strong>{{'hello' | language:lang.selectedLanguage}}{{'world' | language:lang.selectedLanguage}}</strong>
```

**PS:** Don't forget to import the pipe & service in all the components where you want to use this functionality

**Conslusion:**  you can write your own logic to fetch the appropriate Language.json file based on user selected language and use it in the service above mentioned